# Gigabit NIC stuck on 100mbs

Tags: switch, ethernet, layer1, cable, interface

My main problem started when i installed 4 `gigabit` `NIC` into my computer.

The 4 `NIC` are connected to `GB` `linksys` switches, each in different location,1 of the 4 gives `GB` and the others are stuck on `100 mbs`.

When i move the cable of the `GB` to another `NIC` the other `NIC` change to `GB`, so i checked all the cable using digital network tester, but it seems all the cables are good.
I tried to change the switches, same problem, so what do you suggest?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after hours of troubleshooting and testing, i changed the whole cable despite the cable tester shows that nothing wrong with it, and despite it was working , but showing 100 mbs, but for no reason i known after changing the cable the NIC shows GB, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your 1000BASE-T interfaces connect using 100BASE-TX is that your cables are not correctly built. 1000BASE-T requires all four pairs to be correctly wired, while 100BASE-TX only requires two pairs. Using a two-pair cable on 1000BASE-T will cause it to negotiate to 100BASE-TX.

Comment: I know that, i connected the 4 pairs, and i checked it with the cable tester

Comment: That doesn't mean that all four pairs are wired correctly. Cheap cables and testers may give you false positives. The cable must correctly have the twisted pairs, not split pairs. (1-2, 3-6, 4-5, 7-8). If the cable is wired incorrectly (e.g. 1-2, 3-4, 5-6, 7-8), you may get it to pass a cheap tester and work with 100BASE-TX, but it won't work for 1000BASE-T.

Comment: i cant understand completely, but yes that make a sense, for summarizing, what should be done? to work with crimping tool, and RJ, or what? to use the standard wo-o-wg-b-wb-g-wbr-br or to use something else? or just to try connecting until it fixed, as happened before for me, is the problem in crimping the wires or what?

Comment: Unless you have a very good (read: expensive) cable tester, it is really impossible to say since that's what you need to see if the cable meets all the specifications necessary to run 1000BASE-T. It involves a lot more than a simple wire map. You may be able to rent a high-end tester if you don't have several $1000 in order to purchase one. You also need the correct connectors for the cable type (stranded or solid-core). Using a connector designed for stranded cable will not work correctly with solid-core cable, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

What is the make and model of the cable tester? I bet it's not a cable certifier, so it won't tell you if the cable is of sufficient quality to support gigabit connections.

You need better cables.

Comment: The weird case that i used the same cable for the 4 connections, 1 passed and 3 failed to show gb, i rechecked the cables rj ,but still the same